# Extracting public key information from a PEM certificate

Tags: android, ssl, openssl, sha256, sslpinning

This is the first time I am doing this SSL pinning on Android.

When creating OkHttp, I am adding this code:

```
certificatePinner(
  CertificatePinner.Builder().add(
    "url of the server",
    "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
  ).build()
)
```

the second parameter expects this:

> SHA-256 or SHA-1 hashes. Each pin is a hash of a certificate's Subject Public Key Info, base64-encoded and prefixed with either sha256/ or sha1/.

I was given a certificate in a txt file that starts with `--BEGIN CERTIFICATE--` and ends with `--END CERTIFICATE--`.

I am struggling to extract the hash of Public Key Info and convert it to base64.

So far I have tried these methods:

Method 1:
I put the certificate contents without `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` into some string variable. Tried to convert it into `X509Certificate`.

```
private fun certificateFromString(base64: String): X509Certificate? {
        val decoded = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.NO_WRAP)
        val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(decoded)
        return CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(inputStream) as? X509Certificate
}
```

Then I pass this certificate here to get Sha256 hash of the public key. Also, pay attention to `c.encoded` and `c.publicKey.encoded`. I am not sure if the method works correctly.

```
private fun getFingerprint(c: X509Certificate?): String {
    var certificate = ""
    try {
        val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
        var publicKey = ByteArray(0)
        if (c != null) {
            publicKey = md.digest(c.encoded) // I tried both
            publicKey = md.digest(c.publicKey.encoded) // I tried both
        }
        val hexString = StringBuilder()
        for (aPublicKeyByte in publicKey) {
            val appendString = Integer.toHexString(0xFF and aPublicKeyByte.toInt())
            if (appendString.length == 1) hexString.append("0")
            hexString.append(appendString)
        }
        certificate = hexString.toString()
    } catch (e1: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
        e1.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e1: CertificateEncodingException) {
        e1.printStackTrace()
    }
    return certificate
}
```

then I am converting that string result to base64 like this:

```
private fun base64(openKey: String): String {
    return Base64.encodeToString(openKey.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP).toString()
}
```

then I add the resulting String into the `CertificatePinner` class as `sha256/resultingStringInBase64`.

Method 2:
I changed the `.txt` into `.pem` in order to use `openssl` command line tools.

```
openssl rsa -in myCert.pem -pubout> myCert.pub
```

it returned `writing RSA key`

and when I open the generated `myCert.pub`, I see a text with `---BEGUN PUBLIC KEY---` and `---END PUBLIC KEY---` and a long list of letters between them.

Then I ran this to extract the sha256 hash:

```
openssl rsa -in myCert.pub -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256
```

this gave me a 64 character string `2c180286549...b1ba7`.

Then I ran the command again but added base64 conversion.

```
openssl rsa -in myCert.pub -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 | openssl enc -base64
```

The result is completely different than Method 1. Should it be the same? If so, could someone point me in the right direction? Or show how to properly get the SHA256 of Public Key.

Comment: Certainly `c.publicKey.encoded` should return the public key in SubjectPublicKeyInfo (SPKI) format. Hash that with 256, then base64-encode the output of the hash.

Answer (score 0):

My method I just used recently and worked succesfully:

In your Terminal, where the folder containing public key file is located, write the command:

```
openssl x509 -in yourFile.pem -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

The result will be the your desired string (encoded in base64, which means that it'll have 44 characters, including an equal (`=`) symbol at the end), and must be placed in your Android code after sha256/....

Also, several methods could generate different hashes, so you can have multiple valid strings, meaning that both your generated hashes could be correct.